# how do i get one user input value form one ViewController, to appear in another? (extern/global variables?)

Tags: xcode, uitextfield, global-variables, uilabel, extern

i have a set up 2 sets of Objective-C classes (no xib file)

1. AdultTicketCalculatorViewController

//.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AdultTicketCalculatorViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UITextField *Quantity;
    IBOutlet UILabel *Pricelabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *TotalLabel;
}

-(IBAction)calculate;
-(IBAction)clear;

@end
```

//.m

```
#import "AdultTicketCalculatorViewController.h"

@interface AdultTicketCalculatorViewController ()

@end

@implementation AdultTicketCalculatorViewController

-(IBAction)calculate {

    float x = ([Quantity.text floatValue]);
    float c = x*15;

    TotalLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"$%.2f", c];

}

-(IBAction)clear {

    Quantity.text =@"";
    Pricelabel.text =@"$15.00";
    TotalLabel.text =@"";

}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

{

    [Quantity resignFirstResponder];

}
```

1. AdultPayNowViewController

//.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AdultPayNowViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UILabel *Quantity ,*Price ,*QuantitySpace ,*TotalSum ,*TotalSumSpace;
    IBOutlet UIButton *ConfirmPurchase;

}

@end
```

//.m
(i havent implemented anything yet)

i want to take some user input and calculated values form AdultTicketCalculator and display  them within AdultPayNowViewController in the following manner :

1. UITextField 'Quantity' (AdultTicketCalculatorViewController) to appear in UILabel 'QuantitySumSpace (AdultPayNowViewController)
2. UILabel 'TotalLabel' (AdultTicketCalculatorViewController) to appear in UILabel 'TotalSumSpace'

Comment: Have you tried a singleton?  If you search for singleton tutorial on the web, you should find several resources.  I use singletons to pass data between vc all the time.  It allows you to store any variable and access it from any vc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this one by using two different ways.

1.save the data whatever you want in `AdultTicketCalculatorViewController` this class in `NSUserDefaults` and retrieve the data in `AdultPayNowViewController`.

like this :

```
whenever pushing your view place this code or in 
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
//place here
}
```

in  AdultTicketCalculatorViewController

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject: TotalLabel.text forKey:@"TotalLabel"];
    [defaults setObject: Quantity.text forKey:@"Quantity"];
    [defaults synchronize];
```

and re assign the textfield value in viewWillAppear method.

```
AdultPayNowViewController:
```

in viewWillAppear method place this following code.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   TotalSumSpace.text= [defaults  valueForKey:@"TotalLabel"];
   QuantitySumSpace.text= [defaults  valueForKey:@"Quantity"];
```

2.Synthesize the string objects in `AdultPayNowViewController` and assign the values when you push the screen from `AdultTicketCalculatorViewController`.

Comment: sorry, but can you be a little bit more specific, like can you apply that to the code above, because i have no idea how to apply this onto it

Comment: @juan roldan:tell me one thing in your code where you are pushing the view AdultPayNowViewController?

Comment: what do you mean, im trying to push the values input by the user from AdultTicketCalculatorViewController in terms of the 'quantity' text field, and be able to apply that value int oth AdultPayNowViewController

Comment: what do you mean by the final part, in part 2.

Comment: assign those values in viewWillAppear method in AdultPayNowViewController controller class.

Comment: i tired it, not sure if im doing it right, would it me too much of a hassal to send the file to you, and you tweaking it up for me???

Comment: is there an email address that i can send it to you, because this will make a lot more sense if you see the project as it is, because this is for my school assessment and its the last thing i need to do :/

Comment: i have just sent it to you

Comment: i hav e2 problems with your code 1.my xcode was not latest one means im not using storybords and 2.in your project AdultPayNowViewController.h was missing so i cn't do anything.

Comment: place this code in AdultPayNowViewController.m file  -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    TotalSumSpace.text= [defaults  valueForKey:@"TotalLabel"];
    QuantitySumSpace.text= [defaults  valueForKey:@"Quantity"];
}

Comment: why dont you update it then? you can delete the .m file and make a new one, but just call it the same name, i haven't really the code for the adultPayNow .h file is :
    
    IBOutlet UILabel *Quantity ,*Price ,*QuantitySpace ,*TotalSum ,*TotalSumSpace;
    IBOutlet UIButton *ConfirmPurchase;

Comment: in my case i want to work on older x-code that's why i was not updated.

Comment: ow well, ok dont worry about it then, cos im sort of new to xcode, i dont really know what the code your inputing, is like yeha i get what you mean, but it still confuses me

Comment: finally are you getting the answer or not?

Comment: nice i'l send a mail to you whenever i felt free.